# "renderTo" breaks the execution

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I want to render a toolbar on top of page when the application initiates. 
Running the following in `viewport.js` works when `ext-all-dev.js` is included in the page. but when I use `ext-dev.js` instead, it throw the exception.`Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`

```
Ext.create("Ext.toolbar.Toolbar", {
    renderTo: document.body,
    defaultType: 'button',
    items: [{text: 'foo'}]
    });
```

What is wrong with it? Also running above code in console works with both `ext-dev.js` and `ext-all-dev.js` files. The exception stack is:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function AbstractComponent.js?_dc=1398852700374:170
Ext.define.statics.updateLayout AbstractComponent.js?_dc=1398852700374:170
Ext.define.updateLayout AbstractComponent.js?_dc=1398852700374:3319
Ext.define.afterRender Renderable.js?_dc=1398852701043:195
Base.implement.callParent ext-debug.js:4266
Ext.define.afterRender Component.js?_dc=1398852699982:435
Ext.define.finishRender Renderable.js?_dc=1398852701043:458
Ext.define.render Renderable.js?_dc=1398852701043:784
Ext.define.constructor AbstractComponent.js?_dc=1398852700374:1231
Base.implement.callParent ext-debug.js:4266
Ext.define.constructor Component.js?_dc=1398852699982:377
constructor ext-debug.js:4897
(anonymous function) VM11066:3
Ext.ClassManager.instantiate ext-debug.js:5485
(anonymous function) ext-debug.js:2112
(anonymous function) Viewport.js?_dc=1398852703350:51
```

Comment: The code you posted isn't valid.

Comment: This piece of code is not correct: `items: [text: 'foo']`

Comment: I can't imagine valid javascript. What is in Viewport.js on line 51? The Ext.create() function?

Comment: @A1rPun     `renderTo: document.body,`